# Angular-translate is displaying untranslated keys first then text on the browser when application is slow

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I want to know is there a way to load my JSON file before the page is loaded to avoid asynchronous loading.

Comment: "to avoid asynchronous loading" I think you might have missed the point of angular. Anyway I understand what you mean. You might want to check out: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/1344

Comment: Thanks David for answering...I tried many ways that it didn't help me and I need to resolve this issue as soon as possible..I am new to Angular.

Answer (score 0):

On angular state resolve, before your state is loaded, you can load translation.

Comment: Thanks Marco. can you please post a example?